# MongoDB returns undefined while using find()

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

When I try to get the data using the `find()` method, it returns undefined even it has data within it.

```js
let data = await submissionSchema.find({ reviewed: false }).exec();
console.log(data[0].password, data[0]);
```

it returns the followings

```js
undefined {
  _id: new ObjectId("635fdf4754a0c724794209b3"),
  timestamp: '2022/10/31 22:00:00',
  content: 'TESTING 1 2 3',
  reviewed: false,
  referenceID: '202300763061',
  password: 'asgsag'
}
```

It is quite weird as I can get the value when I log other properties of that data such as `content`, `timestamp` etc. All I cannot get is `password` one, any clues on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I have figured out the reason of it is returning undefined. So I am here to answer my question.

I haven't included the `password` properties in my schema declaration.

```js
const submissionSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  // other properties...
  password: String
});
```

By including the required properties, I would be able to get the data with the `find()` method.